# Packages from private pypi don't find requirements

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools

I'm building a private pypi server and it's working, but the packages that I put there has some requirements from official pypi, but when I try to install my private package, the `install_requires` breaks trying to find the external dependencies in my private repository (I saw this in the log).

When I generate the package locally and try to install like

```
pip install -U package.tar.gz
```

it works and the dependencies are found in the official pypi repository.

What do I miss?

My process looks like:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/
pip install -i http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/
```

And I'm getting:

```
Downloading/unpacking mypackage
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/mypackage/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if 127.0.0.1:8000 has it available
  Downloading mypackage-1.0.tar.gz (399kB): 399kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-LjFfGj/mypackage/setup.py) egg_info for package mypackage

Downloading/unpacking feedparser (from mypackage)
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/feedparser/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if 127.0.0.1:8000 has it available
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement feedparser (from mypackage)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for feedparser (from mypackage)
Storing debug log for failure in /home/rodolpho/.pip/pip.log
```

And in the log I see:

```
Downloading/unpacking feedparser (from mypackage)
  Getting page http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/feedparser/
  Could not fetch URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/feedparser/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

Comment: Try adding `--extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi` to your `pip install` command. See [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption--extra-index-url).

Comment: It works @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso, thanks.

Comment: Great! I'll add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `--extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi` to your `pip install` command. See the documentation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption--extra-index-url).